# How do I know if another user's git pull is complete?

Tags: windows, git

Say a user initiated a `git pull` on a big, big repo on a remote Windows server. It'll take several minutes to complete. I, another user altogether, remote into the same machine and navigate to that same folder. How can I tell if the other user's `git pull` is complete?

For context, this folder clones a remote repo to make files available for sharing from it like a CDN. I'm not interested in sharing the machine with another programmer as part of my workflow. I want to know if our file-share has finished updating.

Comment: The most general answer is that you can't: Git repositories are meant for one user to use at a time. Make your own clone; you'll be much happier that way. The longer answer is that there are various locks and ways of inspecting processes, but I'm not sure about any of the Windows-specific details (I could give Linux answers but they won't apply)—but I'd still say "make your own clone"...

Comment: You can't both complete a pull at the same time. Git will error with `error: cannot lock ref`

Answer (score 0):

Git is a distributed source control system. The intended use here is for you to `git clone` the repo on your local machine and work from it. As you finish pieces of work, you can `git push` to the server. Using a central repo where each developer works on a local one is very common with git. I suggest you do some research on different workflows that are used.

Comment: For context, this folder clones a remote repo to make files available for sharing from it like a CDN. I'm not interested in sharing the machine with another programmer as part of my workflow. I want to know if our file-share has finished updating. (I'll add this to the original question)